# Can't login sql server

Tags: sql-server

I installed SQL server 2014.
The issue is that I can not login using any login credentials. Except for sa and my own windows credentials..

Any ideas?

This is the error:

[image: log]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You simply entered the wrong credentials:
http://itproguru.com/expert/2014/09/how-to-fix-login-failed-for-user-microsoft-sql-server-error-18456-step-by-step-add-sql-administrator-to-sql-management-studio/

> The generic message “Login Failed for User (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)” means you entered invalid credentials when logging into SQL Server. - See more at: http://itproguru.com/expert/2014/09/how-to-fix-login-failed-for-user-microsoft-sql-server-error-18456-step-by-step-add-sql-administrator-to-sql-management-studio/#sthash.vKQ0AhjC.dpuf

Here are a few more links how to solve your problem (at least I hope so :D ):
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_protocols/2006/02/21/understanding-login-failed-error-18456-error-messages-in-sql-server-2005/

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverfaq/2010/10/27/troubleshooting-specific-login-failed-error-messages/

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/08/19/sql-server-login-failed-for-user-reason-token-based-server-access-validation-failed-with-an-infrastructure-error/ - Look for `Possible causes and solutions for State 11`

Comment: The credentials are correct.. But i found some interesting information in the last link you sent me. I'll try that out. Thanks !